# Search API result group by type

Tags: deezer

I'm working on the search feature of Deezer API, and I would to group the results by TYPE, i.e on the website, the results are grouped by artist (2 items), albums (2 items) and so on. So is there a way to do the same with a specific request ?

Thanks

Comment: You mean, execute only one request and get all the results in order to group them by type? Or something else? There is no way to do that with only one request, I'm sorry, you have to use the specific endpoint according to the type you want

Comment: Yes, I thought on the website that only one request was made, allowing to group result by type. So, all requests for each type are made async, and once finished, they are grouped right?

Comment: It is not exactly that, but it is the result, yes, they are grouped at the end of the process.